# Feed a Scanner via String

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, args

Heres my basic goal: Convert a program that uses a Scanner and the keyboard as input into a program that uses the Scanner and java args as input. This will be done programatically for a variety of programs, so I'd like to make as few and as small changes to the actual program itself. I'm able to do this by changing 
`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` into `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(args[0]);`.

Now I can seperate each argument with a space in `args[0]` and the program runs fine, but ONLY if it doesn't use `scanner.nextLine()`. As soon as scanner.nextLine() is used, the scanner munches up the entire String and breaks the program.

I can't figure out a workaround without changing the program structure all together (Removing all the `scanner.nextLine()`s. Is there maybe some sort of character/sequence that will stop scanner.nextLine(), or will it always process the entire String?

Thanks

Edit: My initial idea was to give the scanner a String array and have it go through that, index by index, regardless of which method was used (`next`, `nextInt`, `nextLine`). Is that perhaps possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Look at [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/), it would almost certainly be better than trying to "convert" (kludge) a program that is currently using Scanner.
2. You can just insert newlines in the command line arguments if you really need to.

   ```
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
     StringBuilder cla = new StringBuilder();

     for( String command : args ) {
        cla.append( command );
        cla.append( '\n' );  // newline
     }
     String finalCommand = cla.toString();
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm actually basically finished the project, I just have this bug and then some GUI and finalizing stuff. If #2 works, I'll use that. Otherwise I'll redesign and attempt #1. The \n idea should work well, thanks!